# Semantics of 'unchecked call' in Java

Tags: java, generics, types

Consider the following code:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new C(new ArrayList<Object>());
    }

    static class C<T>  {
        public C(final List<String> b) {

        }
    }
}
```

Under javac 1.6.0_30, this code compiles without error (though there is a warning for the raw type).  It appears that if a type is used in a raw manner, all generic type checking for that type is turned off.  This appears to be what the compiler means by unchecked call, but it seems strange that it disables ALL generic checking and not just the generics in that class.  Is this the correct behavior according to the JLS or just a compiler bug?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much how it works.

Comment: Once you have a "raw"`ArrayList`, where would the type mismatch come from?  There's nothing left for the compiler to complain about.  Or else everything genericized in collections would fail when passed a raw type.

Comment: Using a raw type `C` treats the entire class as erased, so `List<String>` becomes `List`.